# How to find out where the process comes from in Linux?

Tags: linux, process

Currently, I find that there are some weird processes in my VPS. See the screen dump [ps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYX12.png) the weird processes are `bmzcvkboqq` and `yrvccvxkeh`. They will restart again and again with different name each time. I have tried to kill them at a same time, but they still come out several minutes later. I doubt that my VPS may have been hacked by someone. I want to find out how these processes come out and which program triggers them. Is there any command or log can show such information?

Comment: have you tried `strace` ?

Comment: You shouldn't doubt. Your VPS has been hacked. It really has.

Comment: @nos (T ^ T) do you know how to recover it?

Comment: @authprivate should i trace all the active processes?

Comment: Thanks all, I find out the root cause, there is some one encounter such case before: http://m.blog.chinaunix.net/uid-20332519-id-4941140.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `$ pstree` to display a tree of running processes. And pipe through to `grep` if there's too many of them: `$ pstree | grep <proc_name> -B 10` (for 10 preceding lines, just increase the number to see more lines above).

Comment: Thank you, I know which program they are running, but I don't know where these programs/processes come from.

Answer (score 0):

Use pstree like Jan Samek said above to trace the PPID. Most likely one of your web apps got hacked and shell is dropped in via a vulnerability in web app. Check cron to see if new jobs are added and you can find the vulnerable app by looking through your web app logs [apache/tomcat whatever you are running].

Comment: Thank you, It is cron trigger these processes, after stop crond, these processes didn't come out again, but I don't know how to verify the configure of cron, nothing was showed by crontab -l, do you have any idea?

Comment: check if any cron files got updated or added. ex: find /etc/cron* -mtime -1 -ls  [-1 means files modified in last 1 day/24 hours, you can increase that in case your VPS got hacked before that]